# Ruby on Rails what is "say" method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was taking a look at the template file [@excid3](https://github.com/excid3) did for his great tool [Jumpstart](https://github.com/excid3/jumpstart) (the public one). Taking a look at the [template file](https://github.com/excid3/jumpstart/blob/master/template.rb), I saw from line 274 on, a bunch of `say` methods, it looks like the normal `puts` but if you take a look closer, there is a line that says:

`say "Jumpstart app successfully created!", :blue`

It gives color to the text! I know that some gems can do that too.

Taking a look at the apidock, [it exists](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Migration/say) as an `ActiveRecord::Migration` class method but there is no more information about it; just [some comment someone did in a deprecated version](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Migration/say/class#211-print-standard-looking-messages-during-migration).

It is strange that it can be used in a template file when it is an `ActiveRecord::Migration` class method, or not?

Comment: This is probably the [`say`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/thor/Thor%2FShell%2FBasic:say) method from [Thor](http://whatisthor.com/). Try inspecting `method(:say)` – it should reveal its origin.

Comment: @Stefan It looks like it can be that but not sure. I removed Thor from my gems and the template is throwing me some dependency errors. But when doing ```method(:say)```, it shows me: ```undefined method 'say' for class Class (NameError)``` (I reinstalled Thor btw to test that... and I'm testing it in a basic .rb script, also tried in a project created using the template and same behavior)

Comment: @Stefan I just found out and indeed it is a Thor method, can you post the answer? Also I found why the method ```method(:say)``` was not working for me and it was because ```say``` is an **instance** method, so it should be ```Thor.new.method(:say)```

Comment: By now, you probably put much more time into this than I did. It's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I'd like to see your findings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is an instance method of the class [Thor](https://rubygems.org/gems/thor/versions/0.19.1?locale=en).

You can take a look to a clear example [here](https://github.com/rails/thor/issues/526).

How to use it standalone? With the same example as in the question to log the text with blue color:

`Thor.new.say "Jumpstart app successfully created!", :blue`

Comment: Source: [`Thor::Shell::Basic#say`](https://github.com/rails/thor/blob/main/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb#L97)